# How do I get texture slot to show up?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I am currently using a premade model to paint on and I'm still figuring out how it all works on Blender. Followed several tutorials when it comes to uv painting and I come to a problem of why the painting doesnt show up on the render: the texture slot in the drawing tool settings is missing and nothing I found helped me try to get it to show. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and its getting super frustrating.

file im using: https://workupload.com/archive/LRNZyvxpKH

[image: painting doesnt show in rendered mode]

Comment: hello please pack your image and share your file

Comment: how do I do that ?

Comment: File > External Data > Pack Resources then use https://blend-exchange.com/ or workupload

Comment: okay thank you, edited to include the file

Comment: You haven't packed the image called astrum_body.001 so I can't try to paint on it, also look at the material, it's super complicated and your image is not directly plugged into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF so I guess that's why you don't see it in render, have you made this material yourself? Can't you simplify it?

Comment: was using this model https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zqHrxfTKb-i6lDGpFqMm3vszSvO6HSfS/view to customize and was using what tutortials were provided from the creator. I don't know how to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Your material is super complicated, no image texture is directly plugged into the shader, if you just want to paint on the body, unwrap again with the *Smart UV Project* mode, create a new material, assign it to the body, plug a new *Image Texture* into the *Base Color* of the *Principled BSDF*, paint:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the section of mesh you want to paint on in object mode, then select the material face you want the paint on, go into texture painting.

Click tools tab on the right, then at the top of your main window in the middle there is a little drop down(if you have your top bar flipped to the bottom it will be in the middle bottom).
[image]
Click the drop down, there you will find the mode, all your materials listed, and a + to add the texture slot. Then you can just select brush, color and paint without needing to use nodes for now.
[image]